# Angular Controller showing $ is not a function error in Dynamic Routing

Tags: angularjs, function, controller, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create an Angular Dynamic Routing. My routing is like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/blank.html' });
    $routeProvider.when('/:name', { templateUrl: 'partials/blank.html', controller: PagesController });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  }]);
```

Here I am using `$http` to get a template file inside a controller and compile it to a div id like this:

```
function PagesController($scope, $http, $route, $routeParams, $compile) {
  $route.current.templateUrl = 'partials/' + $routeParams.name + ".html";

  $http.get($route.current.templateUrl).then(function (msg) {
    $('#view-template').html($compile(msg.data)($scope));
  });
}
```

In the template view, I have a div like this:

```
<div id="view-template" ng-view></div>
```

I thought the above code will compile and add the html data to the div but I am receiving the error that says: `$ is not a function`. What have I got wrong here?

**EDIT:** *After the help from the comments and answers below*

***SOLUTION:***: I was playing around with this a bit more and I went with another solution for this. I added the `$route.current.templateUrl` to the `$scope.theTemplateUrl` and then used `ng-include` in the template file. That did the trick and I also dont need to use the jquery `$` function to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: it appears angular can't find jquery. How have you injected it into your app?

Comment: @JBNizet Your comment is not helpful at all. To us, it's obvious it's an jquery error... but obviously he doesn't know that. He also didn't ask for any advice on his controller. I know it's best practice, but it doesn't effect his issue in this case.

Comment: @ShanRobertson: What is obvious to you is not to me. It looks, to me, like the OP thinks angular is based on jQuery, and that $ is a built-in function that can be used as if he was using jQuery. That's not the case, hence my comment. And just because he doesn't ask for any advice on his controller should not prevent me from helping him, by telling him that DOM manipulation should not be part of a controller. The point of this site is to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make a fiddle.  The limited scope of this snippet inhibits help :)

By just looking at what you are doing I can only make a few recommendations.  But I think your issue lies in .html().

1. Stop using jQuery while you learn Angular.
2. Use $scope to change content on page.  Instead of

   $('#view-template').html($compile(msg.data)($scope));

do this

```
$scope.viewTemplate = msg.data
```

then use angular in your view :)

1. Only use the controller to coordinate the flow of information.  There should not be and DOM manipulation happening here.  The DOM should reflect a state of the controller.
2. Define routes in your app config.  This is not correct.

   $route.current.templateUrl = 'partials/' + $routeParams.name + ".html";

I have some example site in my github repo that you can look at if you want to see a few full sites working: https://github.com/breck421

It seems like you have missed some key parts of Angular.  Make sure you take your time and learn it right.  It will make you life much easier later.

Thanks,

Jordan

Added for a route provider example:

```
MyApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'js/views/index.html',
    controller: 'AppController',
    activeTab: 'home'
})
.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'js/views/index.html',
    controller: 'AppController',
    activeTab: 'home'
})
.when('/thing1', {
    templateUrl: 'js/views/thing1.html',
    controller: 'Thing1Controller',
    activeTab: 'thing1'
})
.otherwise({redirectTo: 'home'});
```

}]);

Then use links like this: Components

EDIT Adding a compile directive per request:

```
angular.module('CC.directive.Compile', [], function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.directive('compile', ['$compile', function($compile) {
        // directive factory creates a link function
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(
                function(scope) {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
                },
                function(value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            );
        };
    }]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jordan. I was trying to create a dynamic angular routing and I was trying to adapt from this tutorial I read here: https://github.com/gregorypratt/AngularDynamicRouting  

I will try add the value to the scope. However if I do `$scope.viewTemplate = msg.data`, do I also need to compile the html fetched via `$http` so I am able to display it in view?

Comment: I looked at that repo.  I do not think it is a good idea at all.  Just because you can do something in JavaScript does not mean you should.  If you need more of a flexible routing solution, try ui-router, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.  I use it at work with a very complex angular app.  You may have to compile your msg.data still.  I have done that with a compile directive I wrote.  Then you would have something like this: <div compile="msg.data"></div>  Out of curiosity, why is your promise returning html.  Seems too rigid of a solution.

Comment: The reason the promise is returning the html is because I am using the routeprovider to identify the template Id that is passed on dynamically and then show the html for that template id.

Comment: using a compile directive to compile the msg.data seems like a good method. Would you be able to share the snippet on your compile directive if possible please? I will also try to have a crack at it and see if I can..

Comment: Sure.  Ill put it up too.  But take a look at how I am doing my routing.  This way I do not need to compile my templates; angular does it.

Comment: So the compile directive is up but I challenge you to try the routing first.

Comment: Thank you @Breck421 for the example of the routing. I use that method and it works well for a set number of urls. But lets say, I have a large number of templates inside a folder (for example urls to cars like `/cars/ford`, `/cars/holden`, `/cars/ferrari` etc..) then  instead of routing each file in the folder separately, creating a dynamic routing like '/cars/:type' will reduce redundancy. But in this case we need to compile it since the controller will be the one returning the view's html. (Thankx for the compile directive!)

Comment: I was playing around with this a bit more and I have come up with another solution for this. I added the `$route.current.templateUrl` to the `$scope.theTemplateUrl` and then used `ng-include` in the template file. That did the trick and I also dont need to use the jquery `$` function to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Your compile directive is still helpful. I have added that to my codes. Thank you so much. All of your support has helped me resolve this.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$` function is defined by jQuery, not angular. Make sure that you have included the jQuery library in order to use `$`

Comment: $ is Angular too.  Angular also has jQuery lite natively included.